# MKMapView hiding MKPointAnnotation when zoom

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkpointannotation

I need to show all MKPointAnnotations added to MKMapView all the time, but they keep hiding when zooming in and out the map, is there a property o delegate method to prevent this behavior ?

Thank you!.

Here is my code:

```
var _mapviewMap: MKMapView!
var _mapAnnotations:[MKPointAnnotation] = []
```

Then add annotations to the map:

```
for item in _resultSet {

        guard let itemCoordinates = item.location?.coordinate else {
            continue
        }

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = item.name ?? ""
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: itemCoordinates.latitude, longitude: itemCoordinates.longitude)
        _mapviewMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
        _mapAnnotations.append(annotation)
}
```

Thats it, not using any delegate methods. I would like to point out that annotations reappear when I zoom in again, it's more like a default behavior I would like to prevent.

Comment: You need to show your code... What have you done so far? Do you do anything when the map is rendered?

Comment: Thank you Rashwan, I've edited the question.

Comment: zip your project and upload it to Dropbox/Google drive and send the link here and I’ll have a look. Hard to tell what’s wrong with the code you have provided here.